# How to unlock Sweet Tooth in Rocket League?

Tags: ps4, rocket-league

How do you get Sweeth Tooth's ice cream van (from Twisted Metal) in Rocket League?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Note: Sweet Tooth is a PS4 exclusive vehicle

To get Sweet Tooth you just need to complete at least one game with all of the new vehicles in Rocket League.  *Merc* and *Venom* are not required: these are the cars from the original game, *Supersonic Acrobatic Rocket Powered Battle Cars*.

Games can be played either offline or online.

- Road Hog
- Hotshot
- Breakout
- Backfire
- Octane
- Paladin
- X-Devil
- Gizmo

Comment: Does online/offline and ranked/unranked matter? It seems that my online wins are currently not being tracked in the garage.

Comment: Updated.  Seems I was wrong about actually needing wins.

Comment: I'm not sure if the win was required, but I played until I got a win with each car, then Sweet Tooth was unlocked.

Comment: Octane and Backfire are the cars from SARPBC.

Comment: @Almo Huh,  I don't know then, the conditions seem to be a little hazy.